# Function Create but Statement is Ignored

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, create-function

[image]

Hello everyone, please help me again!

I could create the function but when I execute it, I always get the following error. Line 1, column 7 (I guess it's datatype of parameter) and statement ignored! :(

Comment: Reading error messages for fun and profit... `'FCT1' is not a procedure or is undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are using is to execute a function. Either assign the result to a variable or run sql query using `dual`

```
 declare
    x varachar2(100);
 begin
    x := fct1('dd');
 end;
```

Alternatively you can also use

```
select fct1('dd') from dual;
```